# Get the Youtube User ID

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm working on an app that uses the youtube API.
I need to get the watchlist of the user and I already found the following snippet

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userId/watch_later?v=2
```

In the API documentation they say

> You need to replace the string userId with the user's YouTube user ID or YouTube username.

How can I get the userID of the user on the device? 
Is there a API so I can request the youtube ID from the youtube application on the device?